# how do we register multiple Views from the same module with PRISM?

Tags: mvvm, prism

I have an MVVM module that has two views. This module is used in two separate PRISM  applications.

How do I tell the Shell which View is has to display?

Comment: What do you currently have in `BootStrapper.InitializeShell`?

Answer (score 2):

The shell doesn't know what view to display. The shell only offers a region:

```
<Window x:Class="PCRS.Client.Shell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Regions="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Regions;assembly=Microsoft.Practices.Prism" >
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl Regions:RegionManager.RegionName="MainRegion"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The module has to register the view to the region it should be presented in:

```
[Module(ModuleName="MyModule")]
public class MyModule : IModule
{
    public void Initialize( )
    {
        RegionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion( "MainRegion", typeof( MyView ) );
    }
}
```

The region manager now takes care of placing the view into the specified region.

If you have two views used in different applications you can register MyView1 to the region called MyView1Region and the MyView2 to the region called MyView2Region:

```
RegionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion( "MyView1Region", typeof( MyView1 ) );
RegionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion( "MyView2Region", typeof( MyView2 ) );
```

Now you can decide by naming the region in the shell which view to use.

But I think you should not use PRISM or you should rethink your design. PRISM is made to decouple the application modules and to not have the one and only Shell that knows the whole application composition. Using PRISM enables you to have the modules decide where toput their views inside the user interface. As far as you want to have this power of decision still inside the shell you don't need PRISM. It's more likely for you to use the standard MVVM pattern.